# HTTP post request failed from sending on server

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to post these variable threw an engine which gives back a responce but while testing it localy on VStudio everything is normal. When i upload it on the server the post request are not precessed.

```
Dim webStream As Stream
Dim s As HttpWebRequest`enter code here`
Dim res As HttpWebResponse
Dim webResponse = ""
Dim enc As UTF8Encoding
Dim postdata As String
Dim postdatabytes As Byte()

s = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://private.pin-pay.com:3902/")
enc = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
postdata = "PN=961" & ddlPhone.SelectedValue & txtMobilePhone.Text & "&TI=" & TransactionID.Text
postdatabytes = enc.GetBytes(postdata)
s.Method = "POST"
s.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
s.ContentLength = postdatabytes.Length
Using stream = s.GetRequestStream()
    stream.Write(postdatabytes, 0, postdatabytes.Length)
End Using
res = s.GetResponse()

webStream = res.GetResponseStream()
Dim webStreamReader As New StreamReader(webStream)
While webStreamReader.Peek >= 0
    webResponse = webStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
End While
```

Comment: A handful of question to help you improve your question: What do you expect to happen ? What happens instead ? Any errors ? Have you tried try-catching and analyzing the stack trace ?

Comment: Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customError

Comment: That just means "something went wrong but I'm not going to tell you", follow the provided instructions to get to the real error.

Comment: after try catch exception i got    A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 195.112.208.220:3902